# Installation issue with augustus 3.3.2

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

> mkdir -p bin cd src && make make[1]: Entering directory
>   `/home/dcb/Documents/sof/augustus-3.3.2/src' echo "-Wall
>   -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-strict-overflow -pedantic -g -ggdb -O3 " > cxxflags make[1]: Leaving directory`
>   /home/dcb/Documents/sof/augustus-3.3.2/src' cd auxprogs && make
>   make[1]: Entering directory
>   `/home/dcb/Documents/sof/augustus-3.3.2/auxprogs' cd bam2hints; make;
>   make[2]: Entering directory`
>   /home/dcb/Documents/sof/augustus-3.3.2/auxprogs/bam2hints' g++ -Wall
>   -O2   -o bam2hints bam2hints.o -lbamtools -lz  /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:
>   unrecognized relocation (0x2a) in section `.init' /usr/bin/ld: final
>   link failed: Bad value collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make[2]: *** [bam2hints] Error 1 make[2]: Leaving directory`
>   /home/dcb/Documents/sof/augustus-3.3.2/auxprogs/bam2hints' make[1]:
>   *** [all] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/dcb/Documents/sof/augustus-3.3.2/auxprogs' make: *** [all]
>   Error 2

Answer (score 0):

Install via Conda might help

- download miniconda

```
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda2-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Miniconda2-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

- install augustus

```
conda install -c bioconda augustus
```